# Total number of leaves taken by employee in previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables- employee, leave
'leave' table has a field called 'leave_date'.

[image]

I need to check the leaves taken by an employee previous month and update it in employee table. I tried below code but it does not give me required results. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
SELECT 
employee.[employee id],
   count(leave.[Employee ID]) as Leaves
FROM
   leave
   JOIN employee
      ON leave.[employee id] = employee.[employee id]
WHERE YEAR(Leave_Date) = Year(GetDate())
   AND MONTH(Leave_Date) = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
GROUP BY employee.[employee id]
```

Comment: is it mysql or sql server ?

Comment: @AmitVerma sql server

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to get the previous month uses `datediff()`:

```
SELECT l.[employee id], count(*) as Leaves
FROM leave l 
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, l.Leave_Date, GetDate()) = 1;
GROUP BY l.[employee id];
```

Note that you do not need a `JOIN` here, because all the columns you are selecting are in the `leave` table.  You can -- of course -- add the `JOIN` back in if you really do need columns from both tables.

A more efficient method, though, constructs the dates for comparison:

```
SELECT l.[employee id], count(*) as Leaves
FROM leave l 
WHERE l.Leave_DATE < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
      l.Leave_DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))          
GROUP BY l.[employee id];
```

This is more optimizer friendly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do only this

```
SELECT EmployeeId, COUNT(LeaveDate)LeavesCount
FROM Leave WHERE 
YEAR(LeaveDate) = Year(GetDate())
AND MONTH(LeaveDate) = Month(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0))
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

But I will suggest to write Stored Procedure for this as IN case of January month, the year will also change. Just for counting leaves no need to made join with employee table. But if you want to update using the same query then JOIN from employee table will be required.